# Gradle is unable to find zip artifact in composite build if java plugin is applied

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, artifact

I have a Gradle project which creates a zip artifact. I define the artifact via `artifacts.add('default', zipTask)`. I add this project to another project via `includeBuild` and use the zip as dependency (`dependencies { myConfiguration 'org.example:testA:+@zip' }`).
So far so good. It works.

The problem starts when I add the plugin `java` to the first project. For some reason it prevents Gradle from finding the zip artifact.
The error is:

```
Execution failed for task ':doubleZipTask'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':myConfiguration'.
   > Could not find testA.zip (project :testA).
```

Why? How to fix it?

## Complete example:

### Project `testA`

`settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'testA'
```

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'base'
    // Uncomment the line below to break the zip artifact
    //id 'java'
}

group = 'org.test'
version = '0.0.0.1_test'

task zipTask(type: Zip) {
    from './settings.gradle' // just so the zip isn't empty
}

artifacts.add('default', zipTask)
```

### Project `testB`

`settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'testB'

// This line may be commented out in some cases and then the artifact should be downloaded from Maven repository.
// For this question it should be always uncommented, though.
includeBuild('../testA')
```

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'base'
}

configurations {
    myConfiguration
}

dependencies {
    myConfiguration 'org.test:testA:0.0.0.+@zip'
}

task doubleZipTask(type: Zip) {
    from configurations.myConfiguration
}
```

---

### Update 1

I've added some diagnostic code at the end of the `build.grade`:

```
configurations.default.allArtifacts.each() {
    println it.toString() + ' -> name: ' + it.getName() + ', extension: ' + it.getExtension()
}
```

and in the version with `java` plugin it prints:

```
ArchivePublishArtifact_Decorated testA:zip:zip: -> name: testA, extension: zip
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.LazyPublishArtifact@2c6aaa5 -> name: testA, extension: jar
```

However, I'm not sure if an additional artifact can break something.

It doesn't seem to be a problem when I add a second artifact myself.

---

### Update 2

Maybe the zip file isn't the best representation of my intentions. After all, I could build java related files in one project and zip them in another.
However, the problem also applies to war files. (War plugin internally uses the Java plugin so it cannot be run separately.)

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57110795/define-an-artifact-to-be-used-as-a-dependency-in-another-project/57232404#57232404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following setup should work with Gradle 5.6 (when using another attribute it will likely also work with previous versions). It mostly corresponds to your original setup with the exception of the changes indicated by `XXX`.

### Project `testA`

`settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'testA'
```

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'base'
    // Uncomment the line below to break the zip artifact
    //id 'java'
}

group = 'org.test'
version = '0.0.0.1_test'

task zipTask(type: Zip) {
    from './settings.gradle' // just so the zip isn't empty
}

// XXX added an attribute to the configuration
configurations.default.attributes {
    attribute(LibraryElements.LIBRARY_ELEMENTS_ATTRIBUTE,
              project.objects.named(LibraryElements, 'my-zipped-lib'))
}

artifacts.add('default', zipTask)
```

### Project `testB`

`settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'testB'

// This line may be commented out in some cases and then the artifact should be downloaded from Maven repository.
// For this question it should be always uncommented, though.
includeBuild('../testA')
```

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'base'
}

configurations {
    // XXX added the same attribute as in the testA project
    myConfiguration {
        attributes {
            attribute(LibraryElements.LIBRARY_ELEMENTS_ATTRIBUTE,
                      project.objects.named(LibraryElements, 'my-zipped-lib'))
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    myConfiguration 'org.test:testA:0.0.0.+@zip'
}

task doubleZipTask(type: Zip) {
    from configurations.myConfiguration
}
```

---

I have tested this setup both with and without the `java` plugin. I’ve also tested publishing to a Maven repository and letting `testB` take its dependency from there instead of from the included build of `testA`. Adding an additional dependency from `testB` on the JAR artifact of `testA` (`myConfiguration 'org.test:testA:0.0.0.+@jar'`) worked, too.

Some explanation on what (I believe) is going on: Gradle needs a way of determining automatically which local component/artifact in `testA` it can use for substituting the external dependency of `testB`.

- Without applying the `java` plugin, there is only a single component/artifact and my guess is that Gradle then just selects that single one without further ado.
- As you saw, by applying the `java` plugin, another artifact is added to `testA`. Now which one should Gradle take? One would expect that it would look at the file extension specified on the dependency in `testB` but that doesn’t seem to be the case. It seems that Gradle isn’t actually working at the *artifacts* level when substituting dependencies but rather at the *module*/*component* level. You might say we only have one component with two artifacts, so selecting the one component should be straightforward. But it seems that we actually have two *variants* of the same component and Gradle wants to select one of these *variants*. In your own `testB` setup, there is no clue given that would tell Gradle which variant to select; so it fails (with an admittedly bad/misleading error message). In my changed `testB` setup I provide the clue: I tell Gradle that we want the variant that has a specific [attribute](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6/userguide/dependency_management_attribute_based_matching.html#sec:abm_configuration_attributes) with the value `my-zipped-lib`. Since I’ve added the same attribute on the published configuration of `testA`, Gradle is now able to select the right variant (because there is only one that has the required attribute). The file extension on the dependency is still relevant in a second step: once Gradle has selected the component variant, it still needs to select the right artifact – but only then.

Note that we’re actually working on the rim of [what is supported](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6/userguide/composite_builds.html#current_limitations_and_future_work) with composite builds today. See also [Gradle issue #2529](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2529) which states that “projects that publish non-jar artifacts” were not terribly well supported. When I first saw your question I honestly thought we’d be out of luck here … but it seems there’s a way to again step a little closer to the rim ;-)

---

In the comments, the question came up why adding multiple custom artifacts works while applying the `java` plugin breaks the build. As I’ve tried to explain above, it’s not a question of multiple *artifacts* but of multiple *component variants*. IIUIC, these variants originate from different attributes on configurations. When you don’t add such attributes, then you will not have different components variants. However, the Java plugin *does* add such attributes which consequently leads to different component variants in your project(/component). If you’re interested, you can see the different attributes by adding something like the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
configurations.each { conf ->
    println "Attributes of $conf:"
    conf.attributes.keySet().each { attr ->
        println "\t$attr -> ${conf.attributes.getAttribute(attr)}"
    }
}
```

Now where and when to add which attributes? That depends on your setup. I wouldn’t blindly add attributes to all configurations in the hope that that’ll solve things magically. While it might work (depending on your setup), it’d certainly not be clean. If your project setup is as complex and/or special as your question suggests, then it’ll probably make sense to think more deeply about which configurations you need and what attributes they should carry. The first sections of [the Gradle documentation page](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6/userguide/dependency_management_attribute_based_matching.html) that I have linked above are probably a good starting point if you are not intricately familiar with these nuances of configurations in Gradle, yet. And yes, I agree that such logic would best live in a Gradle plugin.

Comment: WOW, it works. Although, I will have to find some way to do it through a custom plugin because I don't like the idea of copying that to dozens of projects. Would it break somethink if I just indiscriminately add this property to each configuration in each project?

Comment: I don't think this is simply problem with multiple artifacts in a single project. Java plugin has to do something more than adding another artifact. I can create a second one on my own and both of them work without me setting any attributes.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I don’t believe it’s a problem with multiple _artifacts_ but with multiple _component variants_. I have updated my answer to elaborate a bit on this. I have also tried to answer your other question.

Answer (score 4):

The issue seems to be a bug in Gradle where the composite build and reference to artifacts are broken.

Some discussion is here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/composite-build-cant-use-included-artifact-in-buildsrc-build-gradle/24978

Bug report: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3768

A workaround would be to move the artifact dependency to a task dependency:

```
plugins {
    id 'base'
}

configurations {
    myConfiguration
}

dependencies {

}

task doubleZipTask(type: Zip) {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('testA').task(':zipTask')
    from configurations.myConfiguration
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that it is the same. The problem you've found concentrates on some weird project structure (I admit I don't understand all of it). It never explicitly points out any issue with java plugin.

Comment: From what I understood is that composite build and artifact dependency is broken quote from the first link "But, if I want to do this in a a buildSrc/build.gradle it stops being able to find the artifact from the composite. Eg my-project/buildSrc/build.gradle"

Comment: Well, I still cannot use that. One of the main reasons why I'm trying to use Gradle is because I can configure it to use repository instead of included build. (I have if clause around `includeBuild('../testA')`.) This really speeds up the compilation in a big tree of projects.